# jquery ajax seems not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my HTML. Just a simple form:

```
<form>
    Username:
    <input type="text" id="username"/>
    <br/>
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is my JS associated with it:

```
function init(){
$("#submit").click(function() {   
    var url = "http:example.com/mail";
    alert("what?");
    $.ajax(url, {
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'username' : $("#username").val(),
            'password' : $("#password").val()
        },
        success : function() {
            alert("done");
        }
    });
});
}
```

After I clicked on the submit button, the `$.ajax` function is supposed to do a post to the URL where I keeps my server running.

However, from my server side log or firebug network monitoring, I didn't see any sign of the POST method. (The first `alert` was triggered but the second wasn't.)

They are two different applications that I developed, so after I did some research, here is one explanation:

> Since `$.ajax()` uses `XMLHttpRequest`, it is subject to XHR's cross-domain restriction. Are your SiteA and SiteB on different hosts/ports? If so, you're seeing the expected behavior.

Is that so? If so, is there any workaround?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are doing this with Ajax? Would a normal form submission work? If so, you wouldn't need to worry about cross domain restrictions.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ - I would recommend binding your function to the form's submit instead of the button's click; that way, you can hit enter after typing your password.

Comment: Be careful posting passwords in cleartext..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `return false;` at the end of the click handler to prevent the default submission of the form. Although once you prevent the form from submitting, you will still have the cross-domain restriction, which is not trivial to solve. Look into [jsonp](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanx, now I remember I had the similar situation before. So this is the restriction isn't it? **Origin chrome-extension://dblkghnlgboodeflkimkclllhcgikcam is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Answer (score 1):

Change your event handler to this...

```
function init(){
$("#submit").click(function(event) {   
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = "http:example.com/mail";
    alert("what?");
    $.ajax(url, {
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'username' : $("#username").val(),
            'password' : $("#password").val()
        },
        success : function() {
            alert("done");
        }
    });
});
}
```

This will stop the form from actually doing a full POST to the server.

Comment: I did, but there is still a restriction that prevents me from posting it. Thankx anyway

Comment: Gotcha... That dern cross browser stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
function init(){
```

$("#submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

```
var url = "http:example.com/mail";
alert("what?");
$.ajax(url, {
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        'username' : $("#username").val(),
        'password' : $("#password").val()
    },
    cache: 'false',
    async: 'false',
    success : function() {
        alert("done");
    }
});
```

});
}